# Extending oVirt hosted engine disk on FC using LVM?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, ovirt

I have a question regarding extending oVirt hosted engine disk. I've checked documentation and the is no information about extending hosted-engine disk. I am using FC storage. Until now I have located the correct Logical Volume on a hosted storage domain. 
My question is can I simply use lvextend on the host currently running the engine or should I use some vdsm tools to extend Logical Volume so that I do not do any harm on hosted_storage Data domain?

Comment: I'd say lv extend and then resize2fs inside the guest should work. but to confirm you better contact the users@ovirt.org list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for answers and tips.

I have successfully extended ovirt hosted engine disk on FC storage. I think it could be done better and more smooth. I think it could be done using vdsm storage mailbox on SPM node.

I did the following:

1. Moved hosted engine to SPM node (storage master node) with live migration.
2. hosted-engine has been put to global maintainance  mode
3. Extended lvm with lvmextend -L+30GB LVM_UUID (LVM_UUID is found in /etc/ovirt-hosted-engine/hosted-engine.conf in vm_disk_vol_id and vm_disk_vol_id variables)
4. Restarted all other nodes hosting ovirt hosted-engine for triggering LVM reload on nodes.
5. hosted engine shutdown and startup

Commands used on SPM and hosted-engine node:

> `hosted-engine --set-maintenance --mode=global`
>
> `lvextend -L+20G /dev/vm_disk_id/vm_disk_vol_id`
>
> `hosted-engine --vm-shutdown`
>
> `hosted-engine --check-liveliness`
>
> `hosted-engine --vm-start`
>
> `hosted-engine --set-maintenance --mode=none`

Comment: Now I keep getting this warning:

   > Failed to update OVF disks  OVF data isn't updated on those OVF stores (Data Center oVirt, Storage Domain hosted_storage).

   > VDSM command failed: Could not acquire resource. Probably resource factory threw an exception.: ()

Answer (score 0):

So you have a FC LUN presented to this host - presumably this is a single-LUN-to-single-host setup due to you using LVM, if not then you have a problem. If this is the case then sure, extend the LUN, rescan, fdisk, vgextend, lvextend, resize2fs the underlying FS and then do what you need with the hosted disk file.

Comment: No it is a FC shared LUN between 4 hosts they all see presented LUN as far as I know sanlock daemon is used for LUN resource locking and sharing on ovirt-ha-agent infrastructure. Maybe there is a vdsm cli tool for resizing and managing storage? One option is to shut down the remaining 3 nodes and resize LV.

Comment: for oVirt this is not a problem. it has its own LVM management system that is cluster aware